# moq, how to test the save method?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I have a save() method, not really sure how to test. below is my code.

```
public interface IRepository<T>
{
    T Get(int id);
    void Save(T item);
    void Delete(int id);
}
```

save method doesn't  return any values back, I cannot compare the value. however, I already have 4 users, after adding another one, I only check the total number of users, is it enough to test it?

```
[Test]
public void Add_a_new_smoothie_user_should_return_total_5_users()
{
    // Arrange

    var totalUsers = _users.Count();

    _mockUserRepository.Setup(s => s.Save(It.IsAny<User>()))
        .Callback((User user) => _users.Add(user));

    var newUser = new User
                      {
                          Id = 3,
                          Email = "newuser@test.com",
                          Password = "1234567".Hash(),
                          Firstname = "",
                          Lastname = "",

                          CreatedDate = DateTime.Now,
                          LastLogin = DateTime.Now,

                          AccountType = AccountType.Smoothie,
                          DisplayName = "",
                          Avatar = "",
                          ThirdPartyId = "",
                          Status = Status.Approved,
                          Ip = "127.0.0.1"
                      };

    // Act

    _mockUserRepository.Object.Save(newUser);

    // Assert

    Assert.AreEqual(5, _users.Count());
    Assert.AreEqual(1, _users.Count() - totalUsers);
}
```

Comment: Can you outline your 'save' method? Do you have its 'code coverage'? I don't think adding 'x' users to your mock will validate the method effectively. You should instead focus on testing all flows (main, alternative, exception, etc.) so that code coverage is reasonably high.

Comment: I don't quite get it you moq repository save method to execute your delegate. What are you testing here? Can you provider tested code that is executed in this test?

Comment: my "save" method just saves a new  user to the database.  I dont have the code yet, just the interface.  I thought you have to write unit test first before writing hte concrete method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are mocking the part of the functionality you are trying to test. These tests will prove nothing, any other than `Add()` method of the data type you are holding the users. In the end it doesn't give any ideas if your repository is working.

You should try to implement a [Database Sandbox](http://xunitpatterns.com/Database%20Sandbox.html) for testing your repository functionality.

Comment: I am using the repository pattern. right now, I only have the interface, dont have the concrete implementation.  I thought that's how you unit testing, write test first, then base on the test, write your concrete method.  can you give me an example how to test save method.  my save method just save a new user to the database.

Comment: "implement a Database Sandbox for testing your repository functionality." I dont think this is unit testing.

Comment: You repository exists so you don't have to worry about DB operations in other classes. You can just mock it when needed and act like there are DB operations going on in your tests. In the end, unit testing or not, you also have to make sure your repository works. I thought that was the thing you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: You should be testing implementations of the classes and mocking its dependencies. At the moment, you can only mock the repository in the tests of other classes that need it to do their work. You can't write test methods for it since you didn't implement it yet.

Answer (score 1):

Never write tests for mocked code, because those tests actually do not test anything (well, except mocking framework implementation).

How to create interfaces with test-first approach? It's easy. Consider you have some `FooController`, which requires some data. At some point (during writing tests for controller) you decide, that there will be some dependency, which will provide that data to controller (yep, repository). Your current controller test requires some functionality to get some `Bar` object from data storage. So, you write test

```
Mock<IBarRepository> repositoryMock = new Mock<IBarRepository>();
repositoryMock.Setup(r => r.GetById(It.IsAny<int>()).Returns(new Bar());
FooController controller = new FooController(repositoryMock.Object);
controller.Exercise();
```

This test will not compile, because at this point you don't have `IBarRepository` interface, which is needed by controller. You create this interface. And you also add method `GetById` to this interface. After that you implement controller.

Good news - when controller will be finished, you will have `IBarRepository` interface definition, which has API very convenient for controller.

Next step is creating `IBarRepository` implementation. I rarely write tests for repositories. But, you can do it several ways:

- If your have data access code, which is used by repository (ORM framework, ADO.NET classes, etc), you can mock these dependencies and verify that your repository implementation makes all required calls to underlying data access code. These tests are pretty brittle. And do not give you much benefit, because rarely repositories contain complex business logic.
- You can do integration testing with real database (e.g. in-memory SQLite) and verify that data is really CRUD-ed in database tables. Those tests also brittle and very time-consuming. But in this case you will be sure, that repository works as it should.

Answer (score 0):

Where your repository is saving? If it is saving in some file, then you can compare your file with some model file (gold) where everything was manually checked and is ok. If is some database then you should mock your database interface, log all insert queries and then compare log with ideal log.