# steps to unit test your mvc3 application?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, unit-testing

I am building my web site using asp.net mvc3.  I have following layers.

controller -> service -> repository

I just started my project, dont have anything there.  I started with the interface first.

```
public interface IRepository<T>
{
    T Get(int id);
    void Save(T item);
    void Delete(int id);
}


public interface IUserRepository : IRepository<User>
{
    User GetUserByLogin(UserLoginViewModel userLogin);
}
```

at this point, should I start writing the unit test or  implement the interface first, writing the concrete repository method, then unit test based on the method I write.

I am so confused , not sure which step should go first.

Comment: Check out the Steve Sanderson books on Asp.NET MVC. He walks you through building an MVC app with unit testing in the perfect amount of detail. I'm guessing you're too new to both MVC and unit testing (TDD) to try to tackle them together, on your own.

Comment: what is the purpose of writing unit test? why you do this? Once you would know the purpose, everything will become clear to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I pointed in your [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11462476/470005), ideally you are writing tests outside-in, defining what dependencies are required by outside objects, and mocking them. This allows you to have completed interfaces of dependencies with nice API.

So, in this example you will create `IUserRepository` interface while you write tests for user's controller. Then you create some class, which implements this interface, and start writing tests for your repository implementation.

Another option (which I like even better) - implement your system iteratively by vertical slices:

1. You write some test for your controller
2. You decide that controller needs repository functionality (e.g. `Save`)
3. You add that functionality to repository interface
4. You mock this interface for controller test, and make it pass
5. You write test for `Save` method of repository implementation and make it pass
6. At this point all slice is tested and working. You return to step 1.

BTW unit-testing of repositories is time-consuming and gives you a little benefit, because usually there is not many logic in repositories. I'd rather go with acceptance tests, which exercise all system and prove that feature is implemented.